# can't modify registration files

Tags: python, html, django, django-crispy-forms

I am learning django through video tutorials.I struck at registration part.When I wrote a bunch of code in registration_form.html,it doesn't show up on the browser.Default page which contains username,email,password,password(again) shows up when i go to url 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register.I am trying to load crispy forms.But it doesn't even showing up on the browser and a paragraph of matter also not coming when i try to load the url.
My registration_form.html is

```
{% extends "registration/registration_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Register for an account" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <input class='btn btn-primary'type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}


{% comment %}
**registration/registration_form.html**
Used to show the form users will fill out to register. By default, has
the following context:

``form``
   The registration form. This will be an instance of some subclass
   of ``django.forms.Form``; consult `Django's forms documentation
   <http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/>`_ for
   information on how to display this in a template.
{% endcomment %}
```

My registration_base.html is

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

and settings.py is

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   #django_ap[s
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  #third_party_apps
  'crispy_forms',
  'registration',
  #my_apps
  'newsletter',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'trydjango18.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
 },]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trydjango18.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
      'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
              }
            }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-     validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
   {
    'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'    STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_in_env","static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS=(
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_in_pro","our_static"),
  #os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_in_pc"),
  #'/var/www/static',
  )
MEDIA_URL='/media/'    MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_in_env","media_root")  
#crispy forms
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK='bootstrap3'
#Django registration redux
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS=7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN=True
SITE_ID=1
```

and mu urls.py is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$','newsletter.views.home',name='home'),
   url(r'^contact/$','newsletter.views.contact',name='contact'),
   url(r'^about/$','trydjango18.views.about',name='about'),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),]
```

my views.py is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SignUpForm,ContactForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
   title='welcome'
   form=SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
   context={
   "title":title,
   "form":form
   }


    if form.is_valid():
      instance=form.save(commit=False)
      full_name=form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
      if not full_name:
          full_name="shocker"
    instance.full_name=full_name
    # print instance.email
    # print instance.timestamp
    instance.save()
    context={"title":"Thank you"}

    return render(request,"home.html",context)

 def contact(request):
   title='Contact Us'
   title_align_center=False
   form=ContactForm(request.POST or None)

   context={
     "form":form,
     "title":title,
     "title_align_center":title_align_center,
    }
   return render(request,"forms.html",context)
```

I don't know where I went wrong.Please help me...

Comment: Where is your template file in the project structure?

Comment: So, the template renders, but you don't see a form? Can you post your project urls.py and the view in question?

Comment: @PatrickBeeson  i have added urls.py.please help me..

Comment: @AndreiAvram my templates folder is in trydjango18/src/newsletter/

Comment: I don't see your views.py... Also does the template render?

Comment: @PatrickBeeson I have updated views.py.

Comment: Do you see anything at /accounts/register/ ? What happens if you just use `{{ form }}`?

Comment: Also, if you're using the latest version of django-registration, check your urls: https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/upgrade.html#urlconf-changes

Comment: @PatrickBeeson I don't know what happened now whole block(username,email,password,password(again)) comes out to be hyperlink.When I hover the mouse pointer the whole block comes out to be hyperlnk.Not only that,login page also looks similar..

Comment: Sounds like you've got some HTML problems in your template...